# Modifying server name after ribbon discovery in zuul

Tags: java, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul

I am using Zuul with spring boot as a reverse proxy for all requests, and I am using ribbon for server discovery like the follwing:

```
zuul:
  routes:   
    service-a:
      path: api/service-a/etc
      stripPrefix: false
      serviceId: service-a
sevice-a:
   ribbon:
    listOfServers: http://server_a.com
```

I would like to modify the server for `service-a` from `http://server_a.com` to `http://prefix_server_a.com` based on some configurations at runtime.

The server is being identified during the execution of `RibbonRoutingFilter`, and then the request is forwarded to backend server.

Does anyone know how can I catch the server name before forwarding the request and modify it before the request is being routed?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding why couldn't this just be done with a different profile on startup - one with a prefixed list of servers, and one non prefixed. Is the hostname of `server_a` changing during runtime?

Comment: This can't be done through different profiles at startup because I mean here the configurations that specify the prefix are determined by the caller (the user/client who initiated the request).
For example, for each request a service runs and determines the prefix, then I am to add the prefix to the hostname.